# error deleting sub-array based on key-value pair

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to delete an array where the key is **[ITEM_ID]** searching the value **4**

I would need to remove the whole array, but I cannot do it.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ITEM_ID] => 4
                [ITEM_MODEL] => BASIC Armario
                [ITEM_FABRICANTE] => 1
                [ITEM_COLOR] => Wenge
                [ITEM_QUANTITY] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ITEM_ID] => 8
                [ITEM_MODEL] => Armario 2 Puertas
                [ITEM_FABRICANTE] => 1
                [ITEM_COLOR] => Roble
                [ITEM_QUANTITY] => 1
            )

    )
```

I'm trying with this code:

```
$array = array("ITEM_ID" => "4");
print_r($array);

unset($array['ITEM_ID']);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop through the array and unset the proper sub-array:

```
// begin looping
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    // check if ITEM_ID is 4
    if($value['ITEM_ID'] == '4')
    {
        // unset the array item using the $key
        unset($array[$key]);
        // stop the loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will retain the keys of the items not deleted. To reset the order of the keys you can do `$array = array_values($array);` outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: @DissidentRage You are correct but why cause more processing overhead if it is not required?

Comment: I'm only providing this as a note *if* it's necessary that the keys are in sequential order. It may not be necessary now, but it'd help to know for reference.